# How to resolve auto completion not working issue on oh my zsh with mac os

Tags: macos, autocomplete, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Am using MAC high sierra , from last 4 days am facing auto completion issue with oh my zsh , getting below error , when trying to get auto completions in in iterm 2 , can any one suggest how to resolve this

```
_get_comp_words_by_ref:16: bad substitution
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you recently make changes to your `~/.zshrc` file? I faced the same issue after adding `source ~/.bash_profile;`. Removing this command resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I opened `~/.zshrc` and looked for `bash_completion`.
Found those line I added for kubernetes:

```
if [ /usr/local/bin/kubectl ]; then source <(kubectl completion zsh); fi

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion;
fi

source <(kubectl completion bash
```

removed them and run `source ~/.zshrc` then reopened the terminal and it worked.